# Convert a MuseScore piece to negative harmony

Tags: musescore, negative-harmony

I'd like to experiment with a large selection of tunes to see what negative harmony does to them but I don't want to spend time converting them note by note.

Does MuseScore have a plugin to automatically convert a piece to negative harmony?

I see that there is a "Mirror Harmony" plug-in but that appears to be a different thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't, but when I get round to releasing my MIDI-based software for converting music to negative harmony, it should be pretty easy to hook it up to MuseScore. I'm leaving this as a comment not an answer because it's not a full solution (yet, anyway). But check out https://negativeharmony.app for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I misjudged the Mirror Intervals MuseScore add-in.

To convert the notes in a melody to negative harmony:

- Download and install to MuseScore [Mirror Intervals](https://musescore.org/en/project/mirror-intervals) addin
- Select the section of music you want to convert to negative harmony
- Plugins > Composing Tools > Mirror Intervals
- Select as your pivot note the note that is a fifth above the root. For example, G is the fifth of the C major scale.
- Press apply.

If you have lead sheet music with chord symbols, the chord symbols will not be converted automatically, you'll have to do that by hand.